# SQL - First Date that a record meets requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have a table - call it `table1_summary T1`. It's a historical table with all data each snapshot month
It has every record for each snapshot month dating back to 2008. So if the record was created in say snapshot month `2013-01-01`, then each month the record will be in this table many times for every snapshot month from create date to current date.

Say this is how my table is lined up I'm using. How do I add to my query to where I'd pull out the first snapshot_month this record was `$0.00` for `Record_Balance`? So for this example `2011-05-31` would be the record I'd want to return.

```
snapshot_date---| Record_Number---|Record_Balance
2011-02-28 ------| 12345 ----------------| 276.00 
2011-03-31 ------| 12345 ----------------| 276.00 
2011-04-30 ------| 12345 ----------------| 175.00 
2011-05-31 ------| 12345 ----------------| 0.00 
2011-06-30 ------| 12345 ----------------| 0.00 
2011-07-31 ------| 12345 ----------------| 0.00 
2011-08-31 ------| 12345 ----------------| 0.00
```

Here is my sample query

```
 Select T1.snapshot_date
 ,T1.Record_number
 ,T1.Record_balance

from table1_summary t1
where t1.record_number = '12345'
```

I want to do it for all records and not limit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the first zero balance for each record number:

```
SELECT
    T1.Record_number,
    MIN(T1.snapshot_date) MinDate
FROM table1_summary t1
WHERE T1.Record_balance = 0
GROUP BY T1.Record_number
```

Comment: ahh thanks, I thought I tried that earlier but guess not (think I had a major brain fart and kept putting min before the record_number). That fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it many ways. One of way is to use CTE with ordering by date:

```
DECLARE @table1_summary TABLE
    (
      snapshot_date DATE ,
      Record_number INT ,
      Record_balance MONEY
    )

INSERT  INTO @table1_summary
VALUES  ( '2011-02-28', 12345, 276.00 ),
        ( '2011-03-31', 12345, 276.00 ),
        ( '2011-04-30', 12345, 175.00 ),
        ( '2011-05-31', 12345, 0.00 ),
        ( '2011-06-30', 12345, 0.00 ),
        ( '2011-07-31', 12345, 0.00 ),
        ( '2011-08-31', 12345, 0.00 ),
        ( '2011-02-28', 12346, 1.00 ),
        ( '2011-08-31', 12346, 0.00 ),
        ( '2011-09-30', 12346, 0.00 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Record_number ORDER BY ( snapshot_date ) ) AS RN
               FROM     @table1_summary
               WHERE    Record_balance = 0
             )
    SELECT  T1.snapshot_date ,
            T1.Record_number ,
            T1.Record_balance
    FROM    cte t1
    WHERE   --t1.record_number = 12345 AND 
            t1.RN = 1
```

Output:

```
snapshot_date   Record_number   Record_balance
2011-05-31  12345   0.00
2011-08-31  12346   0.00
```

Just uncomment `--t1.record_number = 12345 AND` if you want to filter by specific record number.